# Get values from one collection that are used in other (MongoDB)

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm trying to create a small prediction game for football world cup with MEAN stack, but I have a problem that I need to get all the predicted games of user and  all that are not predicted yet separately.

My schemas are (users schema is the default mean-stack):

```
 /** 
 * Prediction Schema
 */
var PredictionSchema = new Schema({
    game_id: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Game'
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    choice: {
        type: Number
    }
});
```

And game schema:

```
var GameSchema = new Schema({
    team1_key: {
        type: String
    },
    team1_title: {
        type: String
    },
    team2_key: {
        type: String
    },
    team2_title: {
        type: String
    },
    play_at: {
        type: Date
    },
    score1: {
        type: Number
    },
    score2: {
        type: Number
    }
});
mongoose.model('Game', GameSchema);
```

Anyway, what I'm trying to achieve is to get all games that are mentioned in all predictions and with the active user.

I tried like this, but it does not work:

```
/**
 * List of Games predicted
 */
exports.allPredicted = function(req, res) {
    Game.find({_id: {$in: Prediction.distinct('game_id')}}).sort('-created').populate('user', 'name username').exec(function(err, games) {
        if (err) {
            res.render('error', {
                status: 500
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(games);
        }
    });
};
```

What's wrong? I got error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/Users/username/Projects/ProjectName/server/views"
```

Any ideas? Thanks! :)

**EDIT:**
Got distinct values, not sure if this the create way of doing it, but anyway works.. almost:

```
exports.allPredicted = function(req, res) {
    Prediction.distinct('game_id').populate('user', 'name username').exec(function(err, predictions) {
        if (err) {
            res.render('error', {
                status: 500
            });
        } else {
            console.log(predictions);
            Game.find({_id: {$in: predictions }}).sort('-created').populate('user', 'name username').exec(function(err, games) {
                if (err) {
                    res.render('error', {
                        status: 500
                    });
                } else {
                    res.jsonp(games);
                }
            });

        }
    });
};
```

Now I need, that it should consider the active user as well. Any help?

Comment: `Prediction.distinct` is an async call.

Answer (score 0):

you can find your active user in
req.user

so try

```
Prediction.find({user : req.user._id}).sort('-created').populate('game_id').exec(function(err, predictions) {
    if (err) {
       res.render('error', {
           status: 500
       });
    } else {
       res.jsonp(predictions);
    }
});
```

This should return all the predictions made by your user and replace the game_id by the game associated.

ps: I don't test it but i think this is the logic of request you're looking for.

ps2 : see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html if you want to populate your users data too